# How to debug in watch mode in VSCode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Node has built-in watch mode, I am wondering how could I debug in watch mode with node instead of nodemon. I have a solution, but I have to generate the package.json file. It's like I generate the package.json and I add a script with watch mode like `node --watch index.js`.
[image]

Then add the script to the debug function to VSCode.
[image]

Then it will restart once we modify the file.
[image]

Does anyone know another solution without using nodemon or generating package.json?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tasks in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) to run node with watch flag

1. Using Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P), enter "Tasks: Configure Task"
   [image: configure tasks]
2. Select "Tasks: Create tasks.json from template"
   [image: how to create tasks from template]
3. Choose "Others". This should create `.vscode` directory and a `tasks.json` file in your project folder
4. Change the task to the following:

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run Node.js in watch mode",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "node --watch ${fileBasename}",
        }
    ]
```

5. To run the task, again, use command palette (ctrl + shift + p):

   - Enter "Tasks: Run Tasks" and select it
   - Select "Run node.js in watch mode"
   - Select "continue without scanning the task output".
6. A new VSCode terminal should open and your js file should be running in watch mode.
   [image: results]
7. (Optional) add `.vscode/tasks.json` to your .gitignore
8. To stop the task, press "Ctrl + c".

Comment: By the way, any other way to run the task more quick?

Comment: Your welcome, there is keyboard shortcut you can configure to run tasks much quicker, it's called `workbench.action.tasks.runTask`, it's unassigned by default.